# File.withWriter make a MissingPropertyException

Tags: groovy

I recently studied how to compile groovy code into a. class file, and then save the .class file to local. But there is a unexpected exception.
Here is the code

```
import gewu.blue.model.DynamicActionContextFactory

def stringResult = "//\n" +
        "// Source code recreated from a .class file by IntelliJ IDEA\n" +
        "// (powered by FernFlower decompiler)\n" +
        "//\n" +
        "\n" +
        "package gewu.blue.action.system;\n" +
        "\n" +
        "import gewu.blue.exception.DataPermissionException;\n" +
        "import gewu.blue.kaovy.ActionContext;\n" +
        "import gewu.blue.model.ErrorInfo;\n" +
        "import gewu.blue.record.PermissionUtil;\n" +
        "import gewu.util.SpringUtil;\n" +
        "import groovy.lang.MetaClass;\n" +
        "import groovy.transform.Generated;\n" +
        "import java.util.List;\n" +
        "import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter;\n" +
        "import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSite;\n" +
        "import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation;\n" +
        "\n" +
        "public class ActionSaveData extends ActionContext {\n" +
        "    private PermissionUtil permissionUtil;\n" +
        "\n" +
        "    @Generated\n" +
        "    public ActionSaveData() {\n" +
        "        CallSite[] var1 = $getCallSiteArray();\n" +
        "        super();\n" +
        "        PermissionUtil var2 = (PermissionUtil)ScriptBytecodeAdapter.castToType(var1[0].call(SpringUtil.class, \"permissionUtil\"), PermissionUtil.class);\n" +
        "        this.permissionUtil = var2;\n" +
        "        MetaClass var3 = this.$getStaticMetaClass();\n" +
        "        this.metaClass = var3;\n" +
        "    }\n" +
        "\n" +
        "    public Object run(List args) {\n" +
        "        CallSite[] var2 = $getCallSiteArray();\n" +
        "        Object record = var2[1].call(args, 0);\n" +
        "        Object fields = var2[2].call(args, 1);\n" +
        "        Object hasPermissionBeforeSave = var2[3].call(this.permissionUtil, record);\n" +
        "        if (!DefaultTypeTransformation.booleanUnbox(hasPermissionBeforeSave)) {\n" +
        "            throw (Throwable)var2[4].callConstructor(DataPermissionException.class, var2[5].callGetProperty(ErrorInfo.class));\n" +
        "        } else {\n" +
        "            var2[6].call(record);\n" +
        "            var2[7].callStatic(ActionSaveData.class, ScriptBytecodeAdapter.createList(new Object[]{record}), ScriptBytecodeAdapter.createList(new Object[]{fields}));\n" +
        "            return record;\n" +
        "        }\n" +
        "    }\n" +
        "}\n"
def baseDir = "/Users/wangkaipeng/Desktop/groovy编译"
new File(baseDir,"demo2"+".class").withWriter('utf-8') { writer ->
    writer.writeLine(stringResult)
}
```

And the Exception detailed information is as followed.
[image]

Comment: Try to run your script in a standard groovy console. I bet you're using groovy version that `idea` does not support.

Comment: You're writing source code to what is usually a binary file.  I think you want that to be "demo2.java", then use the compiler to compile that into a class file.  You got that source code form intellij decompiling a class file from Groovy, and it'll be tied to a specific version of Groovy.  If that was 2.5 and you tried to run it in 4.0 it might not be compatible.